# UnxUtil find utility: -path fails

Tags: windows-8, cmd

What I want to do is `find .. -path "bin\\.*\\.*\.Drivers\..*\.dll"`

But UnxUtils `find` fails me:

```
P:\Utils\lib>find .. -name bin
..\Utils.API\bin
..\Utils.Common\bin
..\Utils.Console\bin
..\Utils.Drivers\Driver\bin
..\packages\ini-parser.2.0\bin

P:\Utils\lib>find .. -path bin


P:\Utils\lib>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Updated: surprised to find Windows developers thought about it: [`findstr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)

```
P:\Utils\lib>for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %d in (`dir .. /s /b ^| findstr "bin.*\.Drivers\..*\.dll"`) do dir %d
```

does quite the same as:

```
$ find .. -ipath "bin.*\.Drivers\..*\.dll" -exec ls {} \;
```

and is not that much longer.

Comment: I am not sure if `-path` is a valid flag.  When you are looking for the DLL, you should be using `-name` instead.

Comment: unxnut, `find --help` lists `-path` among valid test options. AFAIU, `-name` matches file name, while `-path` matches the whole file path.